# Append Javascript arrays or object like python

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, append

I tried different thing like array push and the new Set() .add but i cant achieve a functionality like pythons append. any thoughts? am i missing something?

```
ex. in py
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.append([4, 5])
gives you: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

OR

if im in a for loop and i append to first item

```
item.append(9)
```

gives you: [[1, 9], 2, 3]

the second is the one i want to use inside a 2 for-loops

```
js ex
let b = [1,2,3];
b.forEach(function (item) {
  item.push(9); //error
});
```

maybe its a silly question but i am new to js sorry :S

Comment: Given `x = [1, 2, 3]`, `for n in x: n.append(9)` fails in Python anyway.

Comment: something like this yes. i have an array [1,2,3] and inside a foreach if a case matched i want to append a 9 inside. ex [[1,9],2,3]

Comment: Under what circumstances? What case? Please add the info to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
a.push(#here you can enter the content that you want to add to your array)
#if content is more than 1 then add inside []
document.write(a)
```

Comment: ok it worked with silly way i convert the init data to arrays let b = [[1],[2],[3]]; thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way involves the [Iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol) [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3];
const y = [...x, [4, 5]];

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

You can also use [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
const x = [1, 2, 3]
x.push([1, 2]);

console.log(x);
```